# SecurityException: Permission Denial on Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am trying to read SMS from my android device. I have written the required code however, I am getting permission denial error. I have added User-Permission (READ-SMS) in Android Manifest file. I am getting out of permission error, I am printing it in the Log.i (else block)

My code is given below:

```
public ArrayList fetchInbox()
{
    ArrayList sms = new ArrayList();

    Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[]{"_id", "address", "date", "body"},null,null,null);

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {            Cursor cursor = cr.query(uriSms, new String[]{"_id", "address", "date", "body", "read"}, "address = '+2345679'", null, null);

      getSmsLogs(cursor, MainActivity.this);
        Log.i("Hello", String.valueOf(cursor));

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String address = cursor.getString(1);
            String body = cursor.getString(3);

            Log.i("Hello","======&gt; Mobile number =&gt; " + address);
            Log.i("Hello","=====&gt; SMS Text =&gt; " + body);

            sms.add("Address=&gt; " + address + "n SMS =&gt; " + body);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("Hello", "Out of permission");
    }
    return sms;

}
```

The error message :

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.telephony.SmsProvider uri content://sms/inbox from pid=28309, uid=10060 requires android.permission.READ_SMS, or grantUriPermission()

TargetSdkVersion : 23
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`? What version of Android are you testing your app on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(), "android.permission.READ_SMS") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
...
...
 }
```

and code of sms use this if permission is not present

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(UnlockActivity.this, new String[]{"android.permission.READ_SMS"}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
```

hope it will work